# JavaFX thread synchronization with Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, java.util.concurrent

Is there a way to synchronize a JavaFX Platform thread and a standard Java thread? Currently, when triggered, the JavaFX thread fires before the standard Java thread has finished adding all of the images to the observable list, and so the imageList is updated with a blank collection.

```
private final TilePane imageList;
final File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles();
final List<ImageView> views = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (final File file : files) {
                if (Utils.fileIsImage(file) && !file.isDirectory()) {
                    ImageView view = new ImageView(new Image("file:" + file, 72, 72, false, true));
                    views.add(view);
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageList.getChildren().addAll(views);
        }
    });
```

I'm relatively new to JavaFX and concurrency, and don't have any experience with thread locks, so any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (final File file : files) {
            if (Utils.fileIsImage(file) && !file.isDirectory()) {
                ImageView view = new ImageView(new Image("file:" + file, 72, 72, false, true));
                views.add(view);
            }
        }

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageList.getChildren().addAll(views);
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

Consider adding views one by one as long as they are loaded:

```
if (Utils.fileIsImage(file) && !file.isDirectory()) {
    ImageView view = new ImageView(new Image("file:" + file, 72, 72, false, true));
    views.add(view);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageList.getChildren().add(view);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you very much! Not the most efficient solution for large volumes of images, however, but for now this is a much simpler solution than what I was expecting..

Comment: for large number of images, start several threads (2-4). First put the names of all files in a queue and let each thread poll that queue and exit when the queue is empty.