# JavaFx: bring stage to focus on keypress

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx-8, jnativehook

I'm trying to bring my window to focus on a keypress (using jnativehook), but getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = JNativeHook Dispatch Thread` exception.
```

It seems like I can't change the UI from the hook's thread.

Is there any way, to get the stage to the foreground? I'm open to using other key hooks, if necessary.

Comment: Just wrap the call in `Platform.runLater(...)`. Search this forum for "java.lang.IllegalStateException: not on FX Application Thread".

Comment: Thanks! One of the runLater sample is working, it updates the text of a label. But the main window is still in the backgound, when calling primaryStage.toFront();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making games with JNativeHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403575/making-games-with-jnativehook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) suggested, the `Platform.runLater(...)` works. The issue, that the window still wasn't in foreground, was another problem, which was fixed with a setIconified true-false combo.

Comment: If you need to wrap everything, you may want to use the custom dispatcher here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45423466/773849